# How can I decode JSON Unicode using jQuery in a Select2 dropdown filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Select2 JS and Datatables JS. The data is in JSON format. The data for one value should display as `Animal & Veterinary`. In JSON it appears as `Animal \u0026amp; Veterinary`. The Select2 filter displays it as `Animal &amp; Veterinary`. How can I add a function to the JS below that will decode the Unicode? Below is a function that can work but I dont know how to add it to the JS below.

```
var title = 'Animal & Veterinary';
function stringToSlug (title) {
  return title.toLowerCase().trim()
  .replace(/&/g, 'and')
}
```

Below is the script. This is where I would like to pass the function into the filter. "select2config"

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {
      'use strict';

      // Check condition first if the table class exists then run this init.
      if ($('.lcds-datatable--advisory-committee-materials').length > 0) {

      let pageClass = function () {
          let el = $( 'ul.pagination' ).addClass('pagination-sm');
      }

      // define order of table's control element
      let domStyling = "<'row'<'col-sm-12'lB>>" +
        "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
        "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>";

      var otable9 = $('table.lcds-datatable--advisory-committee-materials').DataTable( {
        // Sort of first date column descending.
        order: [[0, 'desc']],
        deferRender: true,
        deferLoading: 50,
        dom: domStyling,
        ajax: {
                "url": "/datatables-json/advisory-committee-materials-json",
                //"url": "/sites/default/files/actest1.json",
                "dataSrc": ""
            },
        processing: true,
        columns: [
                { "data": "field_publish_date" }, // publish_date 0
                { "data": "title" }, // node title summary 1
                { "data": "field_site_structure" } // site_structure Committee/Topic 2

            ],
        columnDefs: [
                {
                    "type": "date",
                    "targets": [ 0 ]
                }
            ],
        pageLength: 10,
        searching: true,
        autoWidth: false,
        responsive: true,
        lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
        buttons: [
          {
            extend: 'excel',
            text: 'Export Excel',
            exportOptions: {
                        columns: [ 0, 1, 2 ]
                    }

          }
        ],
        initComplete: pageClass,
        drawCallback: pageClass
      }); // end datatable

      // config and initialize filters

      let select2config = {
        maximumSelectionLength: 0,
        minimumInputLength: 0,
        tags: true,
        selectOnClose: true,
        theme: "bootstrap",
      }

      let search = $( '#lcds-datatable-filter--search' ).lcdsTableFilter({
        table: otable9,
        type: 'search'
      });

      let clear = $( '#lcds-datatable-filter--clear' ).lcdsTableFilter({
        table: otable9,
        type: 'clear'
      });

      // wait for ajax call to complete to load column data load
      $('table.lcds-datatable--advisory-committee-materials').on( 'init.dt', function() {

        let committee = $( '#lcds-datatable-filter--committee-topic' ).lcdsTableFilter({
          column: 2,
          table: otable9,
          select2Options: select2config,
          type: 'select',
          dataType: 'datatable'
        });
      })

    }}); // end ready function and condition if the table class exists.
```

Comment: What is the exact outcome you're looking for? The `stringToSlug` function mentioned above will find and replace all instances of `&` (ampersands) and turn them into the word "and". Is that what you want?

Comment: `In JSON it appears as Animal \u0026amp; Veterinary` what you've done there is convert `&` to `&amp;` and then convert the `&` in `&amp;` to its unicode form `\u0026`.  I would say your json should either contain `&amp;` or `\u0026` but not a combination of the two.

Comment: @LMulvey, I want to find and replace `\u0026` in the JSON string with the word `and`. So when it displays in the Select2 filter it is `Animal & Veterinary`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to pass in a function to alter the output of JSON so now the filter displays “Animal & Veterinary” not “Animal & Veterinary” By adding this below. The filter now displays Animal & Veterinary but selecting this in the filter does not match the value in the datatable?

```
let select2config = {
maximumSelectionLength: 0,
minimumInputLength: 0,
tags: true,
selectOnClose: true,
theme: "bootstrap",
escapeMarkup: function (text) { return text; }
}
```